# Webpack/Gulp/Express error: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, webpack, pug

I have a project which consists of a file upload form, which uses an express router and jade/pug template rendering for 2 different views.

I'm attempting to use webpack to compile all my javascript files into one (`backend.js`), and gulp to compile that `backend.js` file, along with 3 .pug files, into another directory.

After webpack compiles the js files contained in the project, it places them in build/backend.js:
[project-after-webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM1vH.png)

And finally, gulp takes the `backend.js` file, along with the pug templates located in another folder in the project, and places them in this structure, compiling `backend.js` to `main.js`, and turning all my pug files into HTML files:
[project-after-gulp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPR7M.png)

The rest of the project is in the root directory.

One of the javascript files is responsible for rendering views upon certain http requests. This is where I'm having trouble. Without gulp and webpack, i'm able to render .pug views with no problem using `res.render()`. However, I'm getting a "no such file or directory" error when I use gulp and webpack. This is how I'm attempting to render the `form.pug` file, which gulp turned into `form.html`.

```js
router.get('/', function list (req, res, next) {
    //res.render('submissions/form.pug'
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'build/submissions/form.html'), {
      submission: {},
      action: 'Add'
    });
});
```

And the console is telling me `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/form.html'`, even though you can see that there is in fact a file there.

I'm not sure if my path is incorrect, if using the `.sendFile` function requires anything i'm missing, or if this is just plain impossible. Any help wuold be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of using `path.join()` ([see the docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path)) is to build a path string compatible with all operating systems.

It takes all path fragments as arguments like so:

```
    router.get('/', function list (req, res, next) {
        //res.render('submissions/form.pug'
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'submissions', 'form.html'), {
            submission: {},
            action: 'Add'
        });
    });
```

Maybe a `/` was missing between `__dirname` and `build` otherwise?

Comment: Just tried this, still getting an error telling me no such file exists

Comment: Does the error corresponds to that line of source code ? Can you provide the full trace in your question? With the code pointed at, if it is not that function ?

Comment: This is the full error: `{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/build/submissions/form.html']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/build/submissions/form.html',
  expose: false,
  statusCode: 404,
  status: 404,
  response: 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat \'/build/submissions/form.html\'' }`

Comment: It's strange that the path starts with `/build/...`. If you check the value of `__dirname` it's correct ?

Comment: yup, value of `__dirname` is `/`